# Pylance has wrong type hint (Any) for class method with additional params

Tags: python, intellisense, pylance

Perhaps best way to explain the issue is with an example:

```py
class Bar:
    pass

class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def class_foobar(cls) -> Bar:
        return Bar()

    @classmethod
    def class_foobar_param(cls, param: str) -> Bar:
        return Bar()

bar = Foo.class_foobar()
bar_param = Foo.class_foobar_param(param="")
```

Now, by hovering on `bar` and `bar_param`, I would expect the Pylance tell me they have the same type: `Bar`. However, `bar_param` shows as `Any`.

Now if we add a default value to `param`, the issue goes away:

```py
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def class_foobar_param_default(cls, param: str = "") -> Bar:
        return Bar()
```

Does anyone knows what is going on here?

Following the suggestion in the comments, here is my environment:
Mac Ventura 13.6, vscode v1.84.2, Pylance v2023.11.10 (installed through vscode extensions), Python v3.11.4

Comment: FWIW I can't reproduce this issue, so it may be down to your environment? Here are my particulars: Windows 10, VS Code 1.78, Pylance v2023.11.10, Python 3.11.3

Comment: I'm running pretty similar versions. Perhaps something specific to Mac? Well, sounds like a bug then. I thought it could be due to the inner workings of the `classmethod` decorator, intended usage or something along those lines

Comment: It's possible it's a Mac thing - if I have a chance, I can try this on my MacBook later to see if Pylance behaves there.